# How need to implement a drop-down list from a tab panel ExtJS 6?

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

I need to implement a drop-down list from a tab panel similar to this

[image]

Did someone face something similar?

I tried to use treelist, but it doesn't really fit in this case, in my opinion.

Comment: Please, read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at the [Ext.menu.Menu](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.menu.Menu.html) in the sencha docs :

[image: It gives you a menu like this]
You can do something like this

```
{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'MyButton',
        menu: {
            xtype: 'menu',
            width: 120,
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'menuitem',
                    text: 'Menu Item',
                    menu: {
                        xtype: 'menu',
                        width: 120,
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'menuitem',
                                text: 'Menu Item'
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'menuitem',
                                text: 'Menu Item'
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'menuitem',
                                text: 'Menu Item',
                                menu: {
                                    xtype: 'menu',
                                    width: 120,
                                    items: [
                                        {
                                            xtype: 'menuitem',
                                            text: 'Menu Item'
                                        },
                                        {
                                            xtype: 'menuitem',
                                            text: 'Menu Item'
                                        },
                                        {
                                            xtype: 'menuitem',
                                            text: 'Menu Item'
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'menuitem',
                    text: 'Menu Item'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'menuitem',
                    text: 'Menu Item'
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```